# How to Use the Android Facebook sdk 4.6.0 inside the Application which requires minimum sdk version 2.3.3

Tags: android, facebook

I need to use facebook latest sdk 4.6.0 in my application. But facebook latest sdk has minimum Android SDK version 15. So how i can use it for my 2.3.3 os version devices. or i need to use the old sdk.

Comment: Is there any sample code you know of showing Facebook SDK working for Android 2.3 ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how i can use it for my 2.3.3 os version devices. or i need to use the
>   old sdk.

Yes, if you are targeting your application on   `2.3.3`  and above version you will have to use older version as Current version of Facebook SDK is no more support API level 14 or Below version.